# Integration problem

Tags: integration, quadrature, polynomials

I want to numerically solve integrals of the form,
$$
I = \int_a^b x^k f(x) dx
$$
where $k$ is a given integer, and $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, expressed as,
$$
f(x) = c_0 + c_1 (x - a) + \frac{c_2}{2} (x-a)^2 + \frac{c_3}{6} (x-a)^3
$$
When $k \geq 0$, the integrand is a polynomial of degree $k+3$ and a standard Gauss-Legendre approach could be used, however this doesn't seem appropriate for the $k < 0$ case. I have tried two methods so far. I need to calculate these integrals for many different limit pairs $(a,b)$ and for all integers $k \in [-100,100]$.

**Method 1**

Directly integrating term by term. Essentially I used Mathematica to find the analytic expressions for the integrals of each of the 4 terms. There are multiple cases to be considered (e.g. when $k=-1,-2,-3,-4$ and otherwise). This leads to a large function where each case involves lots of adding,subtracting and multiplying. I get an answer which is close to correct, but it seems I am losing signficant digits somewhere in the complicated expressions for each term, perhaps due to cancellation problems.

**Method 2**

For this method, I attempted to derive a simple quadrature rule (simlar to Gauss-Legendre). We proceed by assuming,
$$
\int_a^b x^k f(x) dx = w_1 f(x_1) + w_2 f(x_2)
$$
with the weights $w_1,w_2$ and nodes $x_1,x_2$ to be determined. Writing out the equations for the cases $f(x) = 1,x,x^2,x^3$ gives the following nonlinear system of equations.
$$ 
\begin{align}
w_1 + w_2 &= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{k+1} (b^{k+1} - a^{k+1}), & k \neq -1 \\\\ \log{\frac{b}{a}}, & k = -1 \end{array} \right. \\\\
w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 &= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{k+2} (b^{k+2} - a^{k+2}), & k \neq -2 \\\\ \log{\frac{b}{a}}, & k = -2 \end{array} \right. \\\\
w_1 x_1^2 + w_2 x_2^2 &= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{k+3} (b^{k+3} - a^{k+3}), & k \neq -3 \\\\ \log{\frac{b}{a}}, & k = -3 \end{array} \right. \\\\
w_1 x_1^3 + w_2 x_2^3 &= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{k+4} (b^{k+4} - a^{k+4}), & k \neq -4 \\\\ \log{\frac{b}{a}}, & k = -4 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
$$
This system of equations can be solved using a root-finding method. In my experiments, this method provides a more accurate solution than Method 1. However the drawback here is that the equations need to be solved for every pair $(a,b)$ (unlike Gauss-Legendre which can be solved on $[-1,1]$ and then scaled to any $[a,b]$). Also, I had to use a Monte-Carlo approach to find appropriate initial conditions for the weights and nodes in order to get convergence for certain parameters $k,a,b$. So this method, while more accurate, is not very efficient.

**Can anyone think of a better approach which is both accurate and efficient?**

**===EDIT===**

Based on the comments below, I propose the following test case:

```
k = 3
a = 1.017265193370166e+00
b = 1.018359131242105e+00
c0 = 1
c1 = -2.742386086956186e+03
c2 = 5.013787633287243e+06
c3 = -4.583247149493306e+09
```

According to Mathematica's NIntegrate with 60 decimal digits of Working Precision, the answer is

```
truth = 0.00028808155205599365876989193328612177562110
```

With my code for Method 1 (given below), I get the following results in double and quad precision:

```
double_result = 2.880813553929329e-04 relerr = 6.826645419623634e-07
quad_result   = 2.880815520711622e-04 relerr = 5.265359890594515e-11
```

The quad precision result is acceptable, but the double precision result is a bit disappointing, and it seems I should be able to get more accuracy. Here is my double precision code, which just integrates term by term:

```
      result = c0 / (1.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 1 + k);
      result += c1 / (2.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 2 + k);
      result -= a * c1 / (1.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 1 + k);
      result += 0.5 * c2 / (3.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 3 + k);
      result -= a * c2 / (2.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 2 + k);
      result += 0.5 * a * a * c2 / (1.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 1 + k);
      result += c3 / 6.0 / (4.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 4 + k);
      result += 0.5 * a * a * c3 / (2.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 2 + k);
      result -= 0.5 * a * c3 / (3.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 3 + k);
      result -= a * a * a * c3 / 6.0 / (1.0 + k) * powdiff(b, a, 1 + k);
```

The powdiff function computes $a^n - b^n$ is such a way as to minimize catastrophic cancellation:

```
static double
powdiff(const double a, const double b, const int n)
{
  double a_to_n = pow(a, (double) n);
  double result = -a_to_n * expm1(n * log1p((b - a) / a));
  return result;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the result are most welcome.

Comment: I would try method 1 with quadruple precision arithmetic.

Comment: I don't understand how you can lose substantial accuracy. You have four terms of polynomial degree $k\ldots k+3$ which you can integrate analytically on a piece of paper and for which you can add everything up into one formula. Unless your choices for $a,b,k,c_0,\ldots,c_3$ are so that you have something particularly ill-conditioned, it's hard to see how doing four additions loses you much accuracy.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I have edited the question above to give a specific example. Quad precision does seem to give an acceptable result, but double precision is disappointing.